# Need help setting up an XSLT for a TBX file

Tags: xslt

I am new to XSLTs and I need help in creating one for a TBX file.

Here is an example of the TBX code:

```
<termEntry id="eid-1">
  <descripGrp>
    <descrip type="Creator">ejablonski</descrip>
  </descripGrp>
  <descripGrp>
    <descrip type="xDate_CreateTime">2014-01-21T20:47:59Z</descrip>
  </descripGrp>
  <langSet xml:lang="nl-nl">
    <tig>
      <term id="tid-1-nl-nl-1">bureau</term>
      <descripGrp>
        <descrip type="CaseSense">Near</descrip>
      </descripGrp>
      <descripGrp>
        <descrip type="xBool_Forbidden">False</descrip>
      </descripGrp>
      <descripGrp>
        <descrip type="PartialTreshold">Half</descrip>
      </descripGrp>
    </tig>
  </langSet>
  <langSet xml:lang="en-us">
    <tig>
      <term id="tid-1-en-us-3">agencies</term>
      <descripGrp>
        <descrip type="CaseSense">Near</descrip>
      </descripGrp>
      <descripGrp>
        <descrip type="xBool_Forbidden">False</descrip>
      </descripGrp>
      <descripGrp>
        <descrip type="PartialTreshold">Half</descrip>
      </descripGrp>
</tig>
  </langSet>
</termEntry>
```

All I need to display, in their appropriate English or Dutch column, is the following:

```
Dutch       English
bureau      agencies
more Dutch  more English
```

TBX files are a glossary format. In the example above, the elements and attributes are the same except for the xml:lang attribute in langset. One is obviously the Dutch term and the next is the English equivalent.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
      <xsl:output method="html"/>
      <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
          <head>
            <title>Translation</title>
          </head>
          <body>
            <p>
              <xsl:for-each select="/text/body/termEntry/langSet/tig"> <br />
              <xsl:value-of select="langSet =nl-nl/term" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
              </xsl:for-each>
              <xsl:for-each select="/text/body/termEntry/langSet/tig"> <br />
              <xsl:value-of select="term" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
              </xsl:for-each>

            </p>
          </body>
        </html>
      </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

thanks,
Jaime

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  You're more likely to get good responses to questions if you show what you have tried, in a form that allows others to reproduce the problem (I know this is difficult if you have no idea where to start).  Not showing your work gives the impression you haven't done any and just want others to do your work for you.  There is good advice on asking effective questions in the [SO help files](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and in Eric Raymond and Rick Moen's essay [How to ask questions the smart way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html).

Comment: **1.** Please show a full XML; I don't see where the "more Dutch" and "more English" would come from. And you show a path of `/text/body/termEntry` - but I don't see those upper-level elements. **2.** Your output looks like a table, but there is no attempt to produce a table in your XSLT.

Answer (score 0):

using the folowing as input XML:

```
<body>
    <termEntry id="eid-1">
        <descripGrp>
            <descrip type="Creator">ejablonski</descrip>
        </descripGrp>
        <descripGrp>
            <descrip type="xDate_CreateTime">2014-01-21T20:47:59Z</descrip>
        </descripGrp>
        <langSet xml:lang="nl-nl">
            <tig>
                <term id="tid-1-nl-nl-1">bureau</term>
                <descripGrp>
                    <descrip type="CaseSense">Near</descrip>
                </descripGrp>
                <descripGrp>
                    <descrip type="xBool_Forbidden">False</descrip>
                </descripGrp>
                <descripGrp>
                    <descrip type="PartialTreshold">Half</descrip>
                </descripGrp>
            </tig>
        </langSet>
        <langSet xml:lang="en-us">
            <tig>
                <term id="tid-1-en-us-3">agencies</term>
                <descripGrp>
                    <descrip type="CaseSense">Near</descrip>
                </descripGrp>
                <descripGrp>
                    <descrip type="xBool_Forbidden">False</descrip>
                </descripGrp>
                <descripGrp>
                    <descrip type="PartialTreshold">Half</descrip>
                </descripGrp>
            </tig>
        </langSet>
    </termEntry>
</body>
```

applying the following stylesheet

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="html"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>Translation</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Dutch</td>
                            <td>English</td>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <xsl:for-each select="body/termEntry">
                            <tr>
                                <td><xsl:value-of select="descendant::tig[1]/term"/></td>
                                <td><xsl:value-of select="descendant::tig[2]/term"/></td>
                            </tr>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

produces

```
<html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

      <title>Translation</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <table>
         <thead>
            <tr>
               <td>Dutch</td>
               <td>English</td>
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td>bureau</td>
               <td>agencies</td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

Here is more of the code:

```
            <termEntry id="eid-4">
            <descripGrp>
                <descrip type="Creator">ejablonski</descrip>
            </descripGrp>
            <descripGrp>
                <descrip type="xDate_CreateTime">2014-01-21T20:50:15Z</descrip>
            </descripGrp>
            <langSet xml:lang="nl-nl">
                <tig>
                    <term id="tid-4-nl-nl-1">hoedanigheid</term>
                    <descripGrp>
                        <descrip type="CaseSense">Near</descrip>
                    </descripGrp>
                    <descripGrp>
                        <descrip type="xBool_Forbidden">False</descrip>
                    </descripGrp>
                    <descripGrp>
                        <descrip type="PartialTreshold">Half</descrip>
                    </descripGrp>
                </tig>
            </langSet>
            <langSet xml:lang="en-us">
                <tig>
                    <term id="tid-4-en-us-3">capacity</term>
                    <descripGrp>
                        <descrip type="CaseSense">Near</descrip>
                    </descripGrp>
                    <descripGrp>
                        <descrip type="xBool_Forbidden">False</descrip>
                    </descripGrp>
                    <descripGrp>
                        <descrip type="PartialTreshold">Half</descrip>
                    </descripGrp>
                </tig>
            </langSet>
        </termEntry>
        <termEntry id="eid-5">
            <descripGrp>
                <descrip type="Creator">ejablonski</descrip>
            </descripGrp>
            <descripGrp>
                <descrip type="xDate_CreateTime">2014-01-21T20:50:52Z</descrip>
            </descripGrp>
            <langSet xml:lang="nl-nl">
                <tig>
                    <term id="tid-5-nl-nl-1">ontwikkelaar</term>
                    <descripGrp>
                        <descrip type="CaseSense">Near</descrip>
                    </descripGrp>
                    <descripGrp>
                        <descrip type="xBool_Forbidden">False</descrip>
                    </descripGrp>
                    <descripGrp>
                        <descrip type="PartialTreshold">Half</descrip>
                    </descripGrp>
                </tig>
            </langSet>
            <langSet xml:lang="en-us">
                <tig>
                    <term id="tid-5-en-us-3">developer</term>
                    <descripGrp>
                        <descrip type="CaseSense">Near</descrip>
                    </descripGrp>
                    <descripGrp>
                        <descrip type="xBool_Forbidden">False</descrip>
                    </descripGrp>
                    <descripGrp>
                        <descrip type="PartialTreshold">Half</descrip>
                    </descripGrp>
                </tig>
            </langSet>
        </termEntry>
```

So, from the above last code I am hoping to get something like this:

**Dutch**    **English**
hoedanigheid    capacity
ontwikkelaar    developer

And so on with the rest of the terms in the glossary. Also, I see that in your code you have to specify how many instances of the  tag there are, but there may be a few or there may be thousands in a glossary. It would be great if we didn't have to specify how many there are and the code could just read all instances of that tag.

Jaime

Comment: Hi Joel,
Thanks for the code. But it only produces the Dutch and English column headers. None of the terms show up. Just to be clear, what I want is that any terms that are under the Dutch element, <langSet xml:lang="nl-nl"> show up in the Dutch column. And any terms that appear under the English element, <langSet xml:lang="en-us"> show up under the English column.

Comment: from the example above, it outputs the terms. Could you show your input?